# Avahi resolving link-local IPv6 addresses for services/devices on other subnets

Tags: networking, routing, ipv6, zeroconf, avahi

Why is Avahi doing this, and how can I prevent it? Why is this only happening for v6 and not for v4?

The service that I'm trying to access (apt_proxy) is definitively routable using the traditional IP addresses (currently only v4 on my LAN, no v6) but the link-local address resolution is breaking my laptops ability to resolve/connect on WiFi.

As a temporary measure, I've disabled IPv6 in avahi-daemon.conf, but I can't keep doing that as my devices using it increase in number. (Or rather, I could, but it kind of ruins the point of "zero-conf")

Comment: Be gentle, it's my first time. I think I kept my questions/problem general enough to not be an issue while providing enough information about my specific situation to get accurate answers for both myself and anyone viewing this in the future. Let me know if this question doesn't accurately fall within the guidelines, and I'll happily edit.

Comment: Are those "other subnets" on the same broadcast domain? If not, might the router be deliberately proxying mDNS between subnets?

Comment: I found the issue, I think. My mdns repeater was running, just not on the right interface. (I changed interfaces shortly before I got into zeroconf) Probably never should have bothered posting this question, but I truly thought I was stumped. Really, I was just missing the basics. I also fixed my normal IPv6 (now getting global IPs and not just link-local) so it's possible that had something to do with it. I think I'll leave this question up so if someone in the future has this issue, they can see what I went through to get it working.

Comment: @ZacharyHill You can [answer your own question](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer) - you should turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, I think. My mDNS repeater was running, just not on the right interface. (I changed interfaces shortly before I got into zeroconf.) I was just missing the basics. I also fixed my normal IPv6 (now getting global IPs and not just link-local) so it's possible that had something to do with it.

In short: always go back to the basics, people.